# PrimeFaces - Set a JSF component as mandatory

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces and JSF - I need to be able to set a component on the page as mandatory in response to an AJAX event. Is the best way to accomplish this using the following code or is there also a way to accomplish it using JQuery ?

Thanks

```
UIInput componentToChange = (UIInput)  facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("ComponentId");
componentToChange.setRequired(true);
```

Thanks

Comment: That is the best way .

Answer (score 1):

Just set the component's `required` attribute with the desired EL expression.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText ... required="#{bean.required}" />
```

There are even EL ways without needing an additional bean property, but it's impossible to propose one based on the sparse information provided so far.

Use `findComponent()` with care. Think twice if it *really* can't be done just in the view (XHTML) side.